# Deployed Google Scripts Add-On Installed But Not Enabled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a google sheets script that will check a list against a company blacklist. It works great in testing, and we've decided to deploy it for our organization. I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide) guide, which got me 90% of the way through.

However, after deploying the add-on, it is installed but not enabled for users. They must manually navigate to the store page and check "enable in this document" for every single sheet they want it to work in.

Has anyone ever experienced this? I talked to Google support but they didn't know why it would behave that way.

Comment: I would ask the question in the Add-on community:  [Developing add-ons for Google Docs/Sheets/Forms](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a permissions error. Add-ons start installed but not enabled until you click on a menu item. I needed to use a different method of adding menu items so that the add-on could request authorization. [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle) help article proved invaluable.